# Twig set with html button

Tags: html, twig

I have a input field and an submit button. I want twig to "set x = containment of the input field" when the submit button is clicked.

How can i make this?

Edit: my code until now

```
<label for="CoARequest"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control">

<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

And what should be set when i press Submit is

`{% set x = text in input %}?`

Comment: Hi Erik, do you have any code?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Paul I will add the Code but its just the Basic and I dont think it will be very usefull

Answer (score 0):

`set` can also be used to wrap block elements.

```
{% set foo %}
    <div id="pagination">
        ...
    </div>
{% endset %}
```

[Reference](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/set.html)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I think you're going about this the wrong way. Are you using a framework? this seems to be a job for javascript. Is the page reloading after the submit?